# List index out of range ? It should not be

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
def trav(r,c):
  #print("(",r,",",c,")")
  ch = a[r+1][c+1]

  lu= a[r][c]
  #print(lu)
  u = a[r][c+1]
  #print(u)
  ru= a[r][c+2]
  #print(ru)

  l = a[r+1][c]
  #print(l)
  r = a[r+1][c+2]
  #print(r)

  ld= a[r+2][c]
  #print(ld)
  d = a[r+2][c+1]
  #print(d)
  rd= a[r+2][c+2]
  #print(rd)

  a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = a5 = a6 = a7 = a8 = 0

  if(ch == lu-1):
    a1 = trav(r-1,c-1)

  if(ch == u-1):
    a2 = trav(r-1,c)

  if(ch == ru-1):
    a3 = trav(r-1,c+1)

  if(ch == l-1):
    a4 = trav(r,c-1)

  if(ch == r-1):
    a5 = trav(r,c+1)

  if(ch == ld-1):
    a6 = trav(r+1,c-1)

  if(ch == d-1):
    a7 = trav(r+1,c)

  if(ch == rd-1):
    a8 = trav(r+1,c+1)

  return max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8) + 1


while(1):
  row,col = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]

  if(row == 0):
    break

  a = []
  for index in range(10):
    a.append([])
    for jindex in range(10):
      a[index].append('a')

  b = []
  for index in range(row):
    str = input()
    for jindex in range(col):
      a[index+1][jindex + 1] = ord(str[jindex])
      if(str[jindex] == 'A'):
        b.append([index,jindex])

  #print (a)
  #print (b)

  ans = max([trav(x[0],x[1]) for x in b])

  print(ans)
```

The code is generating the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/ABCPATH.py", line 80, in <module>
    ans = max([trav(x[0],x[1]) for x in b])   File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/ABCPATH.py", line 80, in <listcomp>
    ans = max([trav(x[0],x[1]) for x in b])   File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/ABCPATH.py", line 17, in trav
    ld= a[r+2][c] IndexError: list index out of range
```

But according to me it should not, and as I am extremely new to python , I am not able to debug it. Please help

sample input taken:

```
4 3
ABC
CFG
BDH
ABC
```

Comment: Where is `a` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *has* to break

r = a[r+1][c+2]

you're reassigning the value of 'r' in that line. please also note that you shouldn't name your string "str" as it is the name of the python string module and you won't be able to use it.

Comment: +1: You got this just before I did. Both `r` and `c` are equal to 0 before this line and the value of `a[1][2]` at that statement is `66`. There are only 10 lists in `a` so the index will inevitably be out of range. Without knowing exactly what the code is intended to achieve, it is hard for either of us to say what this line *should* be.

Comment: As it is basically the same error as naming a string "str"... At this point the value will always be out of range: that line catches the ord of a char, which will always be greater than the hardcoded range of 10.

Comment: ohh! yikes! Thanks a lot mate! thanks a lot! Wouldn't have seen it at all!